# invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

**Background** - I am trying to create a Twitter bot which listens in real time for certain keywords coming only from certain accounts. When these conditions are met, I would then retweet it with my app, so I can follow with notifications from my main account.

**Problem** - Sometimes, but not always, I will encounter an error while the script is running which gives me the error listed in the subject of this post. I'm unsure what causes it, since it happens intermittently.

**What I've Done** - I've searched for the error; most of what I've found refers to "base 10", not "base 16". For the couple cases I've found where it references base 16, I don't understand the solution well enough to adapt it to my code (self teaching myself on this project).

**Code**

```
    import tweepy
    import json
    import re
    import logging

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("xxxx", "xxxx")
    auth.set_access_token("yyyyy", "yyyy")

    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

    class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
        def __init__(self, api):
            self.api = api
            self.me = api.me()

        def on_status(self, tweet):
            keyword = ["Keyword1", "Keyword2"]
            accounts = ['account1','account2']
            patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in keyword]
            patterns2 = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in accounts]
            there = re.compile('|'.join(patterns))
            there2 = re.compile('|'.join(patterns2))
            if there.search(tweet.text) and there2.search(str(tweet.user.id)):
                print("New")
                tweet.retweet()
    
        def on_error(self, status):
            print("Error detected")

    tweets_listener = MyStreamListener(api)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)
    stream.filter(follow=['account1','account2'])
```

**Error**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _get_chunk_left(self)
    
554             try: 

555                 chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()

556             except ValueError:

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_next_chunk_size(self)
    
521         try:
 
522             return int(line, 16)
    
523         except ValueError:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''
       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IncompleteRead                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

*I then get a couple of incomplete reads, the last line of the error is:*

```
ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be handled in the development version of Tweepy on the master branch by automatically attempting to reconnect. The underlying connection error is likely due to falling too far behind in the stream when processing Tweets. For now, you can attempt to reduce the processing within `on_status`, handle the error by restarting the stream, wait for Tweepy v4.0, or use the development version of Tweepy.

For more context, see https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/237 and https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/448.